# Raise error in ajax call from server side asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an ajax call like this

```
$http.post('../services/name.aspx', packageElement, { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }).
         success(function (data, status, headers, config) {    }).
         error(function(data, status, headers, config) { error function  });
```

And in server-side I am sending a json response for this request. But now I got a condition when I won't be having any data to send to client, when this happens I need to raise the error function in my Javascript code. Is this possible? if not any other alternatives?

Comment: Just return an appropriate status code (i.e. not 200) and the JS error callback will be called rather than success.

Comment: @BenRobinson Can you add a sample code as answer

Comment: You could just return "No data" from the server and in success callback check if data returned is "No data", if it is, then it means server has no data to send to the client.

Comment: @artm I don't want to handle error cases in multiple locations, thats why I want the error callback to be raised. I can handle everything in a single line of code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger error handler of ajax from the server side, you could throw an exception, which will trigger the error handler on the client. Or set HttpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent to indicate there's no data to return.

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.Write("No data");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx